# flowplayer using RTMP and BWCHECK(Band Width Check) get size of video dowloaded from FMS(FLASH MEDIA SERVER)

Tags: video, size, buffer, rtmp, flowplayer

I'm trying to have a minimal idea about how much traffic is made  by each video  when somebody is watching this.

*NOTE:flowplayer is using band width check for RTMP plugin and can change the video quality on the fly.

Is there a way to get the video size loaded in buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows? You could use [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/), it shows you the current download rate of each applications running, like here : http://scr.hu/1pvf/bj0qk, and you can also limit the bandwith available, it's a great tool for testing!

Otherwise on Linux there is [iftop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iftop) for example.

For information you can also use [MonaServer](http://monaserver.ovh) if you are interested in a free media server.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this isn't what I'm looking for. My interest is to have this information from every  client who is watching the video.I'm loking for a javascript(flowplayer api method) solution